# Grouping items in Python dictionary, then singling out those items within the groups

Tags: python, defaultdict

I'm not even sure I am wording this correctly, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this. I have a data set of groups, descriptions, individuals and numbers. Some individuals can be in different groups. Some can have the same description. An example may look like this:

```
GROUP A       DESCRIPTION A       PERSON A       NUMBER
GROUP A       DESCRIPTION A       PERSON B       NUMBER
GROUP B       DESCRIPTION A       PERSON C       NUMBER
GROUP C       DESCRIPTION B       PERSON A       NUMBER
```

What I am attempting to accomplish is getting a certain percentage for each person in a group/description. So first, I loop through the data and add to an array. I then use that to create a defaultdict.

```
for row in data:
    l.append([group, description, person, number])

d = defaultdict(int)
for item in l:
    d[item[0], item[1]] += item[2]

for k,v in d.iteritems():
    print k,v

>>(group, description) (sum of numbers)
```

What I need to do from here is where I get confused. Here's an actual example I am using:

```
GROUP A       DESCRIPTION A       PERSON A       1.14
GROUP A       DESCRIPTION A       PERSON B       1.14
GROUP A       DESCRIPTION A       PERSON C       0.36
GROUP A       DESCRIPTION A       PERSON D       1.07
```

So I get the sum of those figures, 3.71. My next step is taking a single person in that group, and divide their number by the total of their group. Using PERSON C as an example in that group above, then I would get 0.36/3.71 = 0.097. I am not sure how to put this into my code, but it seems like it shouldn't be difficult at all -- but I'm just not seeing it. I have several other steps after this, but I think once I know how to obtain this particular percentage, I can figure the rest out.

Comment: `0.36/3.71 != 0.97`. I'm not sure what percentage you're talking about when you say "getting a percentage".

Comment: Sorry, typo. 0.36 divided by 3.71 is 0.097. That is the figure I am trying to get.

Comment: This would be a good problem to tackle with SQL or SQLLITE

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [
['GROUP A'  ,     'DESCRIPTION A'      , 'PERSON A'  ,       1.14],
['GROUP A'  ,     'DESCRIPTION A',       'PERSON B',       1.14],
['GROUP A'  ,     'DESCRIPTION A' ,      'PERSON C',       0.36],
['GROUP A'  ,     'DESCRIPTION A'  ,     'PERSON D',       1.07],
]


total_score = sum([x[3] for x in data])
target_person = 'PERSON C'
the_score = [ x[3]/total_score for x in data if x[2] == target_person]
print(the_score)
```

Comment: Assuming there are a few rows of GROUP B, how to further group this for just GROUP A, without getting the sum in the numbers in GROUP B? This will just sum everything in data. That's why I thought it would work well to use a defaultdict.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import namedtuple 
personEntry = namedtuple('entry', ['group', 'description', 'person', 'data')

# allEntries is a list in personEntries
groupSum = lambda groupKey: sum ([i.data for i in allEntries if i.group == groupKey])

groupTotals = {}
for key in ['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C']:
    groupTotals[key] = groupSum[key]

percentage = lambda entry: entry.data / groupTotals[entry.group]

for eachEntry in allEntries:
    print eachEntry.person, percentage(eachEntry)
```